# How to give 10% discount on every new registered customer on magento1

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to create coupon code from promotion->shopping cart price rule

```
created with below 
Customer Groups without "NOT LOGGED IN".
Uses per Customer = 1
Coupon = Speciit's Coupon
```

But its not working

Comment: Please run php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Yes now its working..

Comment: @PuspalataPanigrahi, Please check my answer. plz accept and upvote if helps to you

Comment: Community goes crazy here :-D

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following :  **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**